# ¿Por qué al hacer el ejercicio Tour of Heroes me da el error "Cannot find name 'HEROES'"?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy empezando a programar con *Angular2* y estoy haciendo el ejercicio ***Tour of Heroes*** con [este tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).

Estoy en el apartado ***Expose heroes***, donde se explica que tengo que crear una propiedad pública en AppComponent.

Como se explica en el tutorial, he insertado `"heroes = HEROES;"` en el `AppComponent`, pero aparece una línea roja bajo la palabra *HEROES* con un mensaje que dice:

> Cannot find name 'HEROES'.

Este es el código:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: HEROES;
}
```

¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: Debes escribir tu pregunta en idioma español.... @AnabelGarciaFernandez

Comment: Además, por favor no pongas tu código como imagen. Pensemos en usuarios con pantallas chicas o con problemas de vista. Al [edit] tu respuesta y traducirla, por favor agrega el código como texto. Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] al pié de tu pregunta

Comment: Listo! Muchas gracias Mariano.

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/pregunta-cerrada-que-se-vota-para-reabrir-que-despu%c3%a9s-se-deber%c3%ada-cerrar-por-ot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes un pequeño error de tipeo:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
}
```

Tu pusiste

```
heroes: HEROES;
```

Comment: Hola Gerardo. Por favor revisa la guía [__Como elaboro una buena respuesta__]. Para mantener la calidad de los contenidos es importante contestar solo las preguntas [__bien formadas__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este caso, además de que la pregunta __está formulada en inglés__, es un error de sintaxis, no repoducible. Aprecio tu entusiasmo en contestar y el tiempo que te tomes al leer este comentario.

Comment: Tiene sentido, que me sugieres que haga? borro mi respuesta? puedo agregar mi respuesta como un comentario tambien. gracias!

Comment: Sugiero que la dejes, pues de todos modos se va a votar para cierre, pero si @AnabelGarciaFernandez atiende el reporte y la traduce al español, ya tiene respuesta. Gracias. Si no la traduce, la pregunta se cerrará y eventualmente será borrada, junto con tu respuesta.

Comment: la respuesta es correcta, el problema se da al no agregar export en la definicion de la constante HEROES

Comment: Hola @Gerardo. Gracias por tu aporte. En futuras respuestas, te recomendaría esperar a que la pregunta esté completa y correctamente realizada... Y en español, y con el código como texto, no como imagen, claro. Creo que lo más importante es darle​ el ejemplo a los usuarios nuevos de que no se obtienen respuestas a preguntas de mala calidad (o en inglés)... La idea es que el sitio entero tenga preguntas y respuestas con la mejor calidad posible, **dando el ejemplo**.

Comment: Hola a todos. Siento el error, pensé que formular una pregunta en inglés era más correcto porque podría ser entendida por un mayor número de usuarios.  También me apunto el tip de que no debo adjuntar mi código como una imagen. Errores de principiante que evitaré en las siguientes!

Comment: @AnabelGarcíaFernández [Mira esto.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2034)